# Fastest way to write to a log in python

Tags: python, logging, uwsgi, gevent

I am using the gevent loop in uWSGI and I write to a redis queue.  I get about 3.5 qps.  On occasion, there will be an issue with the redis connection so....if fail, then write to a file where I will have a separate process do cleanup later.  Because my app very latency aware, what is the fastest way to dump to disk in python?  Will python logging suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If latency is a crucial factor for your app, undefinitely writing to disk could make things really bad.

If you want to survive a reboot of your server while redis is still down i see no other solutions than writing to disk, otherwise you may want to try with a ramdisk.

Are you sure having a second server with a second instance of redis would not be a better choice ?

Regarding logging, i would simply use low-level I/O functions as they have less overhead (even if we are talking of very few machine cycles)

Comment: In desperation...was going to resort to logging..yeah..bad idea.  I will 1) create a dedicated redis queue, 2) fire off writes not in the uWSGI app but instead to another process connected by zmq.

Answer (score 1):

Appending to a file on disk is fast.

```
:~$ time echo "this happened" >> test.file

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Appending to a file with Python seems to be about the same order of magnitude as bash. The  logging module does seem to add a little bit of overhead:

```
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig(filename='output_from_logging')
counter = 0

while counter < 3:
    start = time.time()
    with open('test_python_append', 'a') as f:
        f.write('something happened')
    counter += 1
    print 'file append took ', time.time() - start

counter = 0
while counter < 3:
    start = time.time()
    logging.warning('something happened')
    counter += 1
    print 'logging append took ', time.time() - start
```

Which gives us this output:

```
file append took  0.000263929367065
file append took  6.79492950439e-05
file append took  5.41210174561e-05
logging append took  0.000214815139771
logging append took  0.0001220703125
logging append took  0.00010085105896
```

But in the grand scheme of things I doubt that this operation will be a very costly part of your code base and is probably not worth worrying about. If you are worried about latency then you should profile your code `python -m cProfile code_to_test.py`. That will tell you how long each of your functions is taking and where your application is spending time. I seriously doubt it will mainly be in logging errors.